# Continuous Integration for all version ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm know CruiseControl.rb used for Continuous Integration but it Prerequisites ruby 1.8.6. please sugguest me a lib sloved for all version ruby. Thanks

http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/documentation/getting_started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity supports Ruby 1.9. I work on a medium-sized Rails team that just switched to TeamCity from CruiseControl and we love it.

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/ruby/tag/teamcity/

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a solution to this using RVM to run the CruiseControl code under Ruby 1.8.7 and the Rails code that is being tested under Ruby 1.9.2:

http://tardate.blogspot.com/2010/12/cruisecontrolling-ruby-192-and-rails.html

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like a good way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integrity or cijoe compatible with ruby 1.9

Comment: On the homepage of Integrity (http://integrityapp.com), it says it works on Ruby "1.8.6 (currently doesn’t work on 1.9.X)". Is that information out-of-date?